# Why I cant upload to public_html in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.1, shared-hosting

I am using shared hosting and I have 2 folders. First one 'laravel' other 'public_html'. I want to upload photo to /public_html/uploads/products/ . But when I uploaded photo, my photo uploading into laravel/public/uploads/products. How can read from there or how can upload into public_html

My uploads path code:

```
class UploadPaths
{
    public static $uploadPaths = array(
        'products_photos'     =>'/uploads/products_photos/'

    );
    public static function getUploadPath($path)
    {
        return public_path().self::$uploadPaths[$path];
    }
}
```

And href codes at below:

```
<a href="{{"/../laravel/public/uploads/products_photos/".$product->photo}}" target="_blank" class="file-alert alert-info">{{$product->photo}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers):

`public_path()`

The public_path function returns the fully qualified path to the public directory:

Your public path is the Laravel public folder, inside your project. If you need another folder, just use it directly, or save in your Config file.

Check this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration

You can get: `$public_path = config('public_path');`

And set in your config file:

```
<?php
return [
    // ...
    'public_path' => '/path/to/public/folder',
    // ...
];
```

Comment: I didnt solve. How can read file from in laravel/public/uploads?

Comment: my problems exactly it is. When I upload photo, laravel/public/products. When I want to read doenst work.

Comment: If you put in your address bar "http ://localhost/app/uploads/my_file.txt" it doesn't open? What message you get?

Comment: Doesn't work because looking below public_html/uploads but my uploads below in laravel/public/uploads. I hope so I could explain